# Can't find the active or selected cell in excel using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to use python to find what the address or coordinates of the currently active or selected cell in an excel spreadsheets currently active sheet.

So far all I've been able to do is the latter. Perhaps I'm just using the wrong words to search. However, this is the first time in two years of writing first VBA and now Python that I haven't been able to just search and find the answer.  Even if it took me half a day.
I've crawled through the code at readthedocs (http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/index.html) 
and looked through the openpyxl.cell.cell, openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet, openpyxl.worksheet.views code. The last seemed to have some promise and led me to writing the code below.  Still, no joy, and I don't seem to be able to phrase my online searches to be able to pinpoint results that talk about finding the actual active/selected cell.  Perhaps this is because openpyxl is really looking at the saved spreadsheet which might not include any data on the last cell to be selected. 
I've tried it both in Python 3.4.3 and 2.7.11.  Using openpyxl 2.4.0. 
Here's the code that got me the closest to my goal. I was running it in Python3.

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.views import Selection
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
print(wb.get_sheet_names())
print(ws)
print(Selection.activeCell)
```

Which gives me the below.

```
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
<Worksheet "Sheet3">
Values must be of type <class 'str'>
```

I put in the first two prints just to prove to myself that I'm actually accessing the workbook/sheet.

If I change the last line to:

```
print(Selection.activeCellId)
```

I get:

```
Values must be of type <class 'int'>
```

I assume this is because these are only for writing not querying.  I've toyed with the idea of writing a VBA macro and just running it from python. However, this code will be used with spreadsheets I don't control.  By people who aren't necessarily capable of fixing any problems.  I don't think I'm capable of writing something good enough to handle any problems that might crop up either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Parfait.     I tried your suggestion and got this. `AttributeError: 'String' object has no attribute 'value'`

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to see the purpose of an active cell for a library like openpyxl as it is effectively a GUI artefact. Nevertheless, because openpyxl works hard to implement the OOXML specification it should be possible to read the value stored by the previous application, or write it.

`ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Charlie Clark!  When trying your suggestion, I get:  'openpyxl.worksheet.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sheetView''  I get that with any combination that includes sheetView.  So I also tried, 'code" 'openpyxl.worksheet.views.sheetView'  just to see the result and got the same.  I also figure that perhaps my intended use isn't going to work since I wanted to modify an open spreadsheet, and found out after I posted that it's locked.

Comment: Didn't figure out how to post code in the comments section properly until my time to edit expired, sorry about that.

Comment: Can't tell whether you're looking at the modules or the objects. The implementation details may have changed slightly but the properties are there in all worksheets.

Comment: For openpyxls version 2.3.2 try with 'sheet_view' not 'sheetView' and to SET the value try these two:

     WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'A4'
     WorkSheetOne.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = 'A4'

You must use both activeCell and sqref or Excel will complain the file is corrupt and then fix it, and A1 will be selected.

Comment: I wanted to do this to simply focus the active cell back to 'A1' so that the spreadsheet looks nice and neat when initially opened by the end user.
BOTH this line: `ws.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'A1'` and also this line: `ws.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = 'A1'`  ...are required as pointed out by Matthew Cox.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the `win32com` library to replicate the Excel VBA property, [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673.aspx). Openpyxl might have a limited method for this property while `wind32com` allows Python to fully utilize the COM libraries of Windows programs including the MS Office Suite (Excel, Word, Access, etc.). You can even manipulate files as a child process as if your were directly writing VBA.

```
import win32com.client

# OPEN EXCEL APP AND SPREADSHEET
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open('example.xlsx')

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets('Sheet1').Activate
print(xlApp.ActiveCell)

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)
xlApp.Quit

xlApp = None
```