# How to Paste to Active Cell in Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

**How is active cell set with the current openpyxl version?**

Charlie Clark Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36763368/4539999 - doesn't work.

It's either the wrong functionality or a bug. In excel if a cell is selected then a paste is performed paste occurs at the active cell (similar to the active sheet). Openpyxl seems to ignore active cell.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
#ws.sheet_view.selection[0].activeCell = 'B4'
#ws.sheet_view.selection[0].sqref = 'B4'
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell = 'B4'
#c = ws['B4']
cell=(['Hello'])
ws.append(cell)
wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You should update the existing question.

Comment: Can you explain why you made this comment when I don't have sufficient privileges to update that question? After checking the guidelines for asking questions I don't understand what I could update. I provided a code stub to allow interaction with a GUI and, although my question was different, that [existing] question was relevant (demonstrating research etc.). I consider it would have been inappropriate to change the 'existing' [different] question or provide an unrelated answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299573/what-is-the-correct-approach-for-a-user-with-low-reputation-to-respond-to-a-comm

Answer (score -1):

Question notes excel pastes into active cell, the ws.append demonstrates number of rows in sheet is zero and image demonstrates an active cell in sheet.

It appears writing to active cell in openpyxl requires active cell to be specifically addressed and in excel it is inferred.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
# set active cell for demo
ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell = 'B4'
# set value of active cell
ws[ws.views.sheetView[0].selection[0].activeCell] = 'Hello'
wb.save('Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer are not appreciated.

Comment: Why a neg for posting a workaround without a comment, edit or better answer?